# How to implement database updates using In App Billing Android

Tags: android, sqlite, in-app-billing

I am trying to implement in app billing in my android app. In my app i am trying to sell digital goods which are backed up by sqlite. I want that when a user purchases my app, some extra (say 100) entries get added to my sqlite tables that are already created in the app. What is the way to do this. Is it possible that I create the whole database with all the entries including the ones i am trying to sell, and hide the paid entries. Then when the user pays for those entries, i unhide them. If i do something like this... is my application more likely to be easily hacked? How can this be implemented. The in app billing version 3 documentation by google is very confusing. Can someone give me guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure and confuse about what you are asking, you have more than 1 question, but what I understand on that basis answering your question.

> **I want that when a user purchases my app, some extra (say 100)
>   entries get added to my sqlite tables that are already created in the
>   app.**

Have some prefenceStorage variable as a flag to check is App is installing first time or not, In case of first time you create you SqliteDatabase

```
sqldb = openorCreateDatabase('.... params ....');
sqldb.executeSQL("create table if not exists <tablename> (field text, field1  integer....)");

 //insert record
     sqldb.executeSQL("insert into <tablename> values(....)");

sqldb.close();
```

loop arround insert record to add you 100 entries on app first installation

> **and hide the paid entries.**

have ispaid field in  your records table, on paid update ispaid field with value of '1' and on record display end use the query like this

```
sqldb.query("select * from <tblname> where ispaid = 0");
```

Comment: What i am asking is that... when a user installs the free version of my app, if i provide all the paid and unpaid database entries in my free version only.. will that not be easy to hack?

Comment: yes its easy to hack! and see here too, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694524/application-passwords-and-sqlite-security

Comment: if sqlite is easy to hack.. do u know any other way i can implement it.

Comment: the link i provided have detailed info regarding the issue, one think you can do is to encrypt your db file.